# how to get the object when selecting checkbox?

Tags: html, angularjs

i got the list of checkboxs form taxlist.
it consist of the two objecs. when i check on the checkbox `taxlist.taxprecent`,`taxlist.taxtype` will bind to `ng-model` `cartoder.tax` like `array`

```
[$promise: Promise, $resolved: false]
0:Resource
__v:0\
_id:"5721d57d5b6691d0107f53c3"
createdAt:"2016-04-28T11:33:02.022Z"
isDeleted:false
modifiedAt:"2016-04-28T11:33:02.023Z"
taxpercent:15
taxtype:"vat"
__proto__:Object
1:Resource
__v:0
_id:"5721ed298ea69da01328cbbc"
createdAt:"2016-04-28T10:59:53.673Z"
isDeleted:false
modifiedAt:"2016-04-28T10:59:53.673Z"
taxpercent:10
taxtype:"service"
__proto__:Object
$promise:Promise
$resolved:true
length:2
__proto__:Array[0]
```

**Html code**

```
 <span ng-repeat="item in taxlist">
   <label>
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="cartorder.tax" ng-checked="{{item}}">{{item.taxtype}}
   </label>
```

I dont know even how to start this. please help how `bind` this data

Answer (score 0):

You can add `ng-change`

```
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="cartorder.tax" ng-checked="{{item}}" ng-change="onChange(cartorder);">{{item.taxtype}}</label>
```

js

```
$scope.onChange = function(cartorder){
};
```